# Text after an underscore except for a specific word

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

Consider the following strings:

```
server
server_secure
server_APAC_secure
server_APAC
server_US
server_US_secure
server_EU_secure
server_ISRAEL
```

The template is straightforward:

1. The string `server`
2. An optional region string (e.g. `US`, `APAC`) prefixed with an underscore. The region string can be any sequence of English letters, except for the word `secure`.
3. An optional `secure`, prefixed with an underscore

I would like to get the list of regions that appear in a set of strings. It is quite simple to do using string manipulation, but I'm quite sure it can be achieved using regex.

**How do I extract the optional region substring from each string?**

Comment: why you do't want to use `split()` method?

Comment: I would like to improve my regex skills. Besides, I think it would be more elegant.

Comment: While its possible, I doubt its more elegant to use regex here :-) You could just `split()` on "_" and then have a straight-forward implementation of your described algorithm without using regex.

Comment: @MichaelW Correct, but I was wondering how can this be done with regexes. `split` (or, even better, removing suffixes and prefixes using slicing) is probably the right way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`server_((?!secure)[a-zA-Z]+)`

The first capture will have the required name.

demo:http://regexr.com?34rlv

Answer (score 2):

Simply match anything that is either followed by a word boundary, or by `_secure`:

```
region = re.compile(r'server_([A-Z]+)(?_secure|\b)')
```

This specifically only matches uppercase characters, you can expand the character class (`[...]`) as needed to match more as needed.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> region = re.compile(r'server_([A-Z]+)(?:_secure|\b)')
>>> example = '''\
... server
... server_secure
... server_APAC_secure
... server_APAC
... server_US
... server_US_secure
... server_EU_secure
... server_ISRAEL
... '''.splitlines()
>>> for ex in example:
...     match = region.search(ex)
...     if match is not None:
...         print match.group(1)
... 
APAC
APAC
US
US
EU
ISRAEL
```

Comment: When using `[A-Za-z]` it matches `secure` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following pattern (added `(?x)` for readability):

```
pat = """(?x)
    ^server
    (?:
        _(?!secure)
        ([^_]+)
    )?
    (?:
        _
        (secure)
    )?
"""
```

The advantage is that the region is group(1) and "secure" is group(2), so you can always use unpacking even if a specific substring is absent:

```
region, secure = re.match(pat, 'server_EU_secure').groups()
print region, secure # EU secure
region, secure = re.match(pat, 'server_secure').groups()
print region, secure # None secure
region, secure = re.match(pat, 'server_ISRAEL').groups()
print region, secure # ISRAEL None
```